# How to write Chinese and Japanese in the one report

Tags: cjk, xecjk, platex

everyone.

It is the 3rd. question about 'platex' or Japanese.

**Question**: In one paper or report, I need to write Chinese and Japanese.

```
 Can I use the \usepackage{CJK}, or what kind of command I should use or write?
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Japanese pLaTeX is incompatible with CJK package, so you can't use CJK package on pLaTeX. Actually it throws no error, but the output from pLaTeX + CJK will be almost always broken (e.g. Commands for changing font-size does not work at all, and Chinese characters are printed in Japanese fonts).

pLaTeX is most suitable for Japanese-only documents. If you need multi-language support, you may choose pdfLaTeX + `CJKutf8` package. (This is a little old solution, but seems commonly used.)

```
%#! pdflatex test.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{CJKutf8}
\begin{document}

\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{min}
こんにちは、日本。
\end{CJK}

\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{gbsn}
汉字
\end{CJK}
\end{document}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It seems that the \usepackage{xeCJK} is a good idea.

Comment: Here is a template on overleaf: https://www.zhihu.com/question/41206352.

But I do not understand so well.