# Combine Chinese, Japanese and Korean text in german/english text with xelatex on debian 11

Tags: xetex, debian, chinese, japanese

Is there a working example of how to use Chinese, Japanese and Korean text in german/english text with `xelatex` on `Debian 11`?

I am aware of the different posts on parts of this question (E.g. [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/45403/255699), [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/483612/255699), [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/604512/255699), [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/343760/255699) or [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/145299/255699)). But they are all either for luatex, work only on ubuntu or windows, use some language package or font that are not available/compatible or are to old and not working with new versions.

Our documents are written in German and/or English and have examples and citations in Chinese, Japanese and Korean. Some times in tables.

We are using `XeTeX 3.14159265-2.6-0.999992 (TeX Live 2020/Debian)` on `Debian 11`.

Comment: [This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/604512/208544) to one of the questions you listed should work, though you should remove the `[Renderer=HarfBuzz]` options as this is luatex only. Of course be sure to change the fonts to something installed on your system as well

Comment: @mbert: As I mentioned I'm aware of this answer. In this answer not only `[Renderer=HarfBuzz]` is not working. Also `import=zh-hant` in `\babelprovide[import=zh-hant]{chinese}` shows problems due to not available package `zh-hant`. `HarfBuzz` can be replaced with `OpenType`. But how to workaround the package `zh-hant`?

Comment: It works on my system, can you post an example file and the log containing the error you get? You might also try replacing `import=zh-hant` with simply `import`

Comment: If you need Traditional Chinese, try `import=zh-Hant`.